# Trying to find a very basic preact.js setup where I can debug the source code

Tags: reactjs, npm, configuration, webpack, preact

My question is (I think) fairly simple. I am trying to dig into the internals of preact.js and am unsure how to do so. What I mean is, I can get the framework to work fine; I do so via the webpack build from the preact-boilerplate setup. Again, works fine, but there seems to be so much transpiling and source-mapping and hot-loading and whatever the heck else makes these frameworks so quick and fancy that I can't seem to actually *intercept the code* so I can do boring debugging stuff like console.log and such.

Of course, I can find the preact source code in the node_modules folder; however, this code does not seem to be the one that is actually running/compiling. I suspect this is because everything is being transpiled in real time due to webpack or babel or who knows what. Anyway -- I just want a setup where I can use preact.js but where I can actually access the code. Think of a normal website with a jquery file in a  tag. Something like that...and while I know I could theoretically do something like add the preact.js to a script tag on the main index.html page, complications arise due to the babel transpilation and such. And as far as there being some way of doing this via a webpack configuration option, that is beyond my pay grade...but such a configuration option would be fine as well. In a perfect world, I would obviously love to have all the fancy webpack stuff, but since this is all for educational purposes, I'd sacrifice that just for the ability to debug the source code...

This is a strange question in that I am actually struggling to make things simple. I feel like I'm asking to watch TV, but while the place is lousy with 90 inch flat screens, I just need a simple black and white with vacuum tubes. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example repo for using preact without any transpiler:
https://github.com/developit/preact-without-babel

You may want to copy preact from unpkg.com/preact so you can edit it locally.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much; that did the trick (after replacing the https script with my local copy). Really appreciate it!